# Принудительная загрузка изображений

Tags: html, css, javascript

Добрый день. Требуется принудительно загрузить все изображения сайта (как в тегах img, так и в стилях - background). Обычно это делает браузер, берёт изображения из кеша или отправляет GET запрос при попытке отображения этого изображения.

В данной ситуации требуется принудительно загрузить всю графику сайта на клиент пользователя, а потом отобразить сайт.

Подобный сайт является игрой, поэтому на этапе загрузки игры. Нужно загрузить всю графику на клиент, что бы не было торможений.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте следующий СSS-хак. Добавляете к body невидимый псевдо-элемент, который содержит все картинки:

```
  body::after {
    content:
        url('image1.jpg')
        url('image2.jpg')
        url('image3.jpg');
    display: none;
  }
```

К моменту window.onload все картинки будут уже закешированы.